How to write a cooking scene without it sounding like a recipe?
I'm a beginner writer.
I would like to know how to write about food being prepared. Food is significant in my short stories. I want to write about food in a comforting and cosy way. I want my writing to feel like a Studio Ghibli food scene. The way Studio Ghibli prepares food feels like it's filled with love and tenderness. How do I translate this cosy feeling onto a page?
Do I use a lot of comparisons, e.g. "My mum's hot choclate was a warm welcome during the winter season. It warmed my body and my heart."

We don't provide feedback, so I have deleted the part of your question that asks for critique.

There is a lot that can go on while a meal is being prepared:

The cook follows a recipe to prepare a specific dish.
The cook is within a space (the kitchen), and that space has certain characteristics (the furniture, the light, where it is situated in the house etc.).
There will be thoughts and emotions in the cook's mind.
The cook may interact with other people, giving them orders or talking to them.
And so on.

During a cooking scene, you (as a writer) can place your focus on any aspect of that scene that you want. In a cookbook the focus will be on the recipe and how the meal is prepared. You can narrate that in a short story or novel as well, if you want, but in most stories the readers will not learn how to prepare what the characters eat. Rather the focus will be on what the meal means for them. For example, your protagonists might be hungry from their adventures and now they finally get to eat while they rest. Or the preparation of the meal can be a moment of meditative contentment. Or something that some friends do together to socialize. And so on.
As a writer, your first task is to understand what the purpose of the cooking scene is within your story. Then decide which aspects of the situation serve this purpose. Finally, when you write, get into the mind of your viewpoint character and "experience" the cooking as they would, given what it means within the context of your story.
If you want to emphasize the coziness of the situation, try and understand what evokes that feeling of coziness in you or your character or other people. Often coziness is an effect of a peaceful, quiet moment (maybe in contrast to the tumultous events that preceded it), of safety (e.g. in a home), of a simple, mundane task (such as cooking), of comfort (both physically and mentally), and so on. So when you want to write a cozy situation, focus on those aspects of the situation that make one feel cozy: the warm fire in the hearth, the cat sleeping on the bench, the smells of the ingredients, the soft bubbling of the soup, the voices of friends or family that drift in from the living room, the feeling of comfortable loose clothing, and so on.

Thanks for this detailed explanation. You brought up great points for me to consider going forward with my writing of cooking scenes.

Good answer, especially the part about describing the pleasant changes to the environment as a result of the cooking—the aroma and sounds etc.
